# How can we diversify the site?

Tags: discussion

Presently, Politics SE has a very strong US bias. From counting country-based tags:

- [united-states](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states): 119 questions
- ([european-union](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/european-union): 11 questions; not a country)
- [uk](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk): 7 questions
- [russian-federation](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/russian-federation): 5 questions
- [italy](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/italy): 4 questions
- [india](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/india) [france](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/france): 3 questions
- [australia](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/australia)
  [cuba](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cuba)
  [finland](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finland)
  [mali](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mali)
  [nepal](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nepal)
  [pakistan](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pakistan) [china](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/china): 2 questions
- [somalia](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/somalia) [sweden](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sweden) [ukraine](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ukraine) [switzerland](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/switzerland) [palestine](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/palestine) [nigeria](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nigeria) [norway](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/norway) [haiti](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haiti) [hungary](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hungary) [iraq](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iraq) [israel](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/israel) [denmark](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/denmark) ([african-union](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/african-union)) [afghanistan](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/afghanistan) [bolivia](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bolivia) [canada](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canada) [venezuela](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/venezuela): 1 question

That's a *very* strong bias. The United States has more than twice the number of questions than *all the other countries combined*.

How can we attract a more diverse public to the site?

Comment: diversity is over-rated

Comment: Why would you want a more diverse public?

Comment: A higher diversity will attract more audience and make the site more interesting for non-US based participants.

Answer (score 5):

Frankly an English language basis, which is part of the terms of service, is always going to overrepresent the Five Eyes - UK, US, Canada, Australia, and New Zealand, at a minimum.

Personally, I've tried to ask international issues - at least 1 Nepalese and 1 Russian question were mine :)  Additionally, I'm still rather proud of my "What do non-US eople think about Abortion" question. I still think this is the best approach - ask questions about non-US things!

I love questions about the U.S. Constitution - don't get me wrong - but I think if we want a more diverse group, we need to ask more questions about the rest of the world.

Answer (score 2):

Chicken and egg. You need to attract more diverse experts. As it is, there seem may be 2-3 people here who care about and/or can answer questions on Russian politics with any degree of knowledge/familiarity. And of them, I generally don't care enough to bother with asking many questions, given they don't generate too much rep due to lower popularity (and heck, I'm only an expert in comparison to an empty set - a well informed observer of Russian politics, not a professional or participant or even a student of it). Pretty sure it's the same for other non-US countries.